# Create a dropdown button in Bootstrap 4 that opens only on caret click

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I want to create a nav item that would be a dropdown, but

- when you click it on the text part, it's a link and takes you to another page;
- when you click it on the caret, it opens the dropdown.

Is there a good way or do I have to switch to hacker mode?

Comment: what have you tried..?

Comment: Reading the docs and seeing that it doesn't seem to be supported natively by Bootstrap. I'm asking if anyone has any experience or ideas for doing this in a sane way, utilising the tools that Bootstrap provides.

Comment: if you need with `nav` let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
Here is full documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#split-button-dropdowns

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><a href="google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=TGOqWcvWNrKH8Qfr4YKgDw">Link</a></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: element a cannot be nested inside element button.

Comment: @AkbarTaghipour op has mentioned `Create a dropdown button in Bootstrap 4 that opens only on caret click
` so nothing to d with nesting inside

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">
         Link
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown- 
   toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
     </div>
     </div>
```